# SWFObject on Safari 6.1 & 7, "Don't trust Flash" option

Tags: javascript, flash, swfobject

SWFObject is pretty fantastic at detecting particular Flash versions, using something like:

```
if (swfobject.hasFlashPlayerVersion("10")) { ... }
```

We use this to provide Flash content to those who support it, and JS-driven content to those who don't.

However, Safari 6.1 and 7 on OSX will present a pop-up when first navigating to a page with Flash content, asking if you trust the plugin.

If I choose "no", then the above detection script will *still pass*, but Safari won't actually display the Flash content, breaking the fallback script entirely.

Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: I don't have an answer or workaround, but it's a great question.

Comment: mulled it over, posted a response.

Answer (score 2):

In some cases it may be as simple as [checking whether the embed was successful](http://learnswfobject.com/advanced-topics/detecting-success-of-dynamic-embedding/). This can be done synchronously via SWFObject's `createSWF` method.

```
swfobject.customEmbed = function (swfLoc, id, w, h, version, color){
   if (swfobject.hasFlashPlayerVersion(version)){ 
      var so = swfobject.createSWF({data:swfLoc,width:w,height:h}, {bgcolor:color},id); 
      //swfobject.createSWF returns an HTML element, not a boolean
      if(so){ return true; } 
  } 
  return false; 
}

var success = swfobject.customEmbed("mymovie.swf", "flashcontent", "550", "400", "10", "#FFF");

if(!success){ 
   //embed failed! do something appropriate
}
```

Caveat: When SWFObject tells you whether the `embed` was successful, it specifically refers to whether the new HTML markup was created, not whether the SWF has actually loaded (for example, SWFObject will tell you it's a success even if the SWF is 404'd).

The only way to ascertain whether the SWF has actually loaded is to [poll the SWF for loading percentage](http://learnswfobject.com/advanced-topics/executing-javascript-when-the-swf-has-finished-loading/):

```
function swfLoadEvent(fn){
    //Ensure fn is a valid function
    if(typeof fn !== "function"){ return false; }
    //This timeout ensures we don't try to access PercentLoaded too soon
    var initialTimeout = setTimeout(function (){
        //Ensure Flash Player's PercentLoaded method is available and returns a value
        if(typeof e.ref.PercentLoaded !== "undefined" && e.ref.PercentLoaded()){
            //Set up a timer to periodically check value of PercentLoaded
            var loadCheckInterval = setInterval(function (){
                //Once value == 100 (fully loaded) we can do whatever we want
                if(e.ref.PercentLoaded() === 100){
                    //Execute function
                    fn();
                    //Clear timer
                    clearInterval(loadCheckInterval);
                }
            }, 1500);
        }
    }, 200);
}

//This function is invoked by SWFObject once the <object> has been created
var callback = function (e){

    //Only execute if SWFObject embed was successful
    if(!e.success || !e.ref){ return false; }

    swfLoadEvent(function(){

        //Put your code here
        alert("The SWF has finished loading!");

    });

};


swfobject.embedSWF("movie.swf", "flashcontent", "550", "400", "10", false, false, false, false, callback);
```

Please reply if either of these approaches work for you, I'm curious about the result. Thanks

Comment: Thanks pipwerks, great to have a member of the SWFobject team answer a question! I'll investigate these options today. Perhaps combining your second approach with a tiny "canary" swf?

Comment: A canary SWF is a great option, if you're OK with potential delay to initial page load. We don't incorporate that approach in SWFObject due to overhead/speed concerns.